# Is it possible to generate a signed certificate with an existing CA which has a different key pair?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, signature, ca, csr

I create a signed certificate with an existing CA as I explained in this post: [Bouncy Castle: Signed Certificate with an existing CA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51750354/bouncy-castle-signed-certificate-with-an-existing-ca)

However, my generated certificate has the same public and private keys that the CA certificate.

Is it possible to generate a certificate which has another key pair?

I have tried the example code in the following post but my pdf signature is invalid: [Generating X509 Certificate using Bouncy Castle Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930381/generating-x509-certificate-using-bouncy-castle-java)

I will appreciate any comment or information that can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A public key certificate (PKC) will have the same key pair (public key) as the issuer **only if** the certificate is a self signed one. It's always possible for a CA to issue a certificate for another key-pair, in which case the new certificate will have the public key of the new key-pair and will be signed by the CA's private key. The subject of this new certificate can in turn be made a CA (through BasicConstraint extension and KeyUsage extension) in which case the new key-pair can be used to issue yet other certificates, thus creating a certificate path or chain. Please see the following code snippet.

```
public static X509Certificate getCertificte(X500Name subject,
                                          PublicKey subjectPublicKey,
                                          boolean isSubjectCA,
                                          X509Certificate caCertificate,
                                          PrivateKey caPrivateKey,
                                          String signingAlgorithm,
                                          Date validFrom,
                                          Date validTill) throws CertificateEncodingException {

BigInteger sn = new BigInteger(64, random);

X500Name issuerName = new X500Name(caCertificate.getSubjectDN().getName());
SubjectPublicKeyInfo subjectPublicKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(subjectPublicKey.getEncoded());

X509v3CertificateBuilder certBuilder = new X509v3CertificateBuilder(issuerName,
                                                                    sn,
                                                                    validFrom,
                                                                    validTill,
                                                                    subject,
                                                                    subjectPublicKeyInfo);

JcaX509ExtensionUtils extensionUtil;
try {
  extensionUtil = new JcaX509ExtensionUtils();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("No provider found for SHA1 message-digest");
}

// Add extensions
try {
  AuthorityKeyIdentifier authorityKeyIdentifier = extensionUtil.createAuthorityKeyIdentifier(caCertificate);
  certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.authorityKeyIdentifier, false, authorityKeyIdentifier);

  SubjectKeyIdentifier subjectKeyIdentifier = extensionUtil.createSubjectKeyIdentifier(subjectPublicKey);
  certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.subjectKeyIdentifier, false, subjectKeyIdentifier);

  BasicConstraints basicConstraints = new BasicConstraints(isSubjectCA);
  certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.basicConstraints, true, basicConstraints);
} catch (CertIOException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Could not add one or more extension(s)");
}

ContentSigner contentSigner;
try {
  contentSigner = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(signingAlgorithm).build(caPrivateKey);
} catch (OperatorCreationException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Could not generate certificate signer", e);
}

try {
   return new JcaX509CertificateConverter().getCertificate(certBuilder.build(contentSigner));
 } catch (CertificateException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException("could not generate certificate", e);
 }
}
```

Please note the arguments:
*subjectPublicKey*: public key corresponding to the new key-pair for which a new certificate will be issued.

*caCertificate*: CA certificate which corresponds to the key-pair of the current CA.

*caPrivateKey*: private key of the CA (private key corresponding to the caCertificate above). This will be used to sign the new certificate.

*isSubjectCA*: a boolean indicating whether the new certificate holder (**subject**) will be acting as a CA.

I have omitted keyUsage extensions for brevity, which should be used to indicate what all purposes the public key corresponding to the new cert should be used.

Comment: In general it's better to use v3 X509 certificate when it's not a self-signed certificate. The authority-key-identifier and subject-key-identifier extensions are helpful in tracing the certificate chain all the way to the root certificate while verifying a certificate or a signature signed by an end-entity (corresponding to an entity certificate). https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1

Comment: I'm trying your code and it works. Thank you very much!